# Github Service (Jenkins) Using Rest API

Tags: rest, github, jenkins, github-api, github-services

We are using Github API `https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/hooks` to create the Jenkins service in the repositoy. We are sending the following body

```
{
  "name": "jenkins",
  "active": true,
  "events": [
    "push",
    "pull_request"
  ],
  "config": {
    "url": "https://anon.com/jenkins/folder1/job/folder2/",
    "content_type": "json"
  }
}
```

When we are using Rest Client to invoke the above API then we are getting the service created in the repository but the url field is coming blank as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above problem was caused due to mistake in  in the body. The correct body for **Jenkins service** using **Github Create hook API** is-

```
{ 
"name": "jenkins", 
"active": true, 
"events": [ 
    "push"
], 
"config": { 
    "jenkins_hook_url": "https://anon.com/jenkins/folder1/job/folder2/"
}
```

}

The differences between this body and the body posted in the question are in the **events** object and **config** object.

Since we are adding a service which will invoke For eg-  a job in jenkins - only event which is required is push and not pull. 
Also in **config** object the parameter's key is **jenkins_hook_url** not **url**.